# How do I make my API available to everyone?

Tags: c, linux, api, libraries, abstraction

I want to create an abstract linked-list implementation (having general operations to *createList*, *destroy*, *addNode*, *deleteNode*, etc.). How do I make these functions available to anyone who is using the OS? (I am using Ubuntu.)

I can have the declaration of a function:

**In add.h:**

```
int add(int a,int b);   /* add.h having the declaration */
```

**In add.c:**

```
#include "add.h"    
int add(int a,int b)    /* add.c having only definition */
{
    return (a+b);
}
```

**In main.c:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"add.h"
int main() 
{
 //use add() here
}
```

How do I have the API set up in the Linux environment such that the implementation in `add.c` is hidden from the user of the API? I don't want to force the users of the API to copy the `add.h` file in their working directory; I'd rather have some way to install it to the Linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution of bobah is not good enough, because you don't want to specify the path where your sources are currently, when you *use* the API, you can install the library into the system directories (/usr/local/lib, /usr/local/include and so on). Then, you wont need `-I` and `-L`. You'll still need `-l`.

You'll need admin rights for that (be root, or use sudo).
Consider using the "install" command.
And "libtool", if you want to build a shared object of your library.
And the autotools (autoconf and automake).

If you mean really anyone, and not just anyone on your computer, with this

> to anyone who is using the OS? (I am using Ubuntu.)

then you'll also need to build a source or binary package. And convince the Ubuntu maintainers to include it into their repository. Which will probably be difficult for yet another linked list library.

Comment: You're welcome. The preferred way to express your thanks is to upvote and/or accept answers ;)

Comment: @Sebastian Yes i am doing this only for the sake of understanding how shared libraries and API's are built . I know there are millions of linked list API's out there . But considering myself as a newb i thought this could be a good way to learn another aspect of this language .

Answer (score 2):

Native APIs are distributed in a form headers+libraries. API user when building his software is specifying headers search paths (-I/dir/with/headers) when compiling source code to object files, and libraries search paths (-L/dir/with/libs) and libraries (-lmylibname) when linking object files to libraries or binaries. Some also like embedding libraries search paths to the libraries and binaries being built, this can be done with -Wl,-rpath=/dir/with/libs linking time gcc flag.

You should prefer #include<> in the public headers as #include"" is first searched in the same directory where the including file resides and this may slow down the compilation.

Most of below operations can be automated with standard development Linux tools (automake, etc.).

Command line to build your API:

```
gcc -c -o add.o -fPIC add.cc -I/dir/where/add_h
```

Command line to link your API:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname=add -olibadd.so
```

Command line to compile the client code (main.c):

```
gcc [-I/dir/with/headers] -o main.exe [-L/dir/with/libs] -ladd [-Wl,-rpath=/dir/with/libs] main.c
```

Comment: @bobah.net is it possible to explain with reference to the code above ?

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi- yep, will update answer with command lines in a moment